# Does extern "C" force limitations on my code?

Tags: c++

Does the standard say anything about limitations on functions used with `extern "C"`? In a [questions of mine that makes no sense to anyone else](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9628663/34537). It appears that when i have a complex class gcc breaks (runtime oddities/errors) if i call a non default constructor (anything with a parameter i believe) and msvc seems to break if it isn't a POD (however i could still use my constructors and it ran fine).

I suspect all the undefined behavior happens because a C library is calling my C++ which returns a type that is exactly the size of a pointer but has operator overloading and constructors. I don't know why it happens and gcc certainly doesn't give me any warnings.

Does extern "C" force limitations on my code? All i know is exceptions can't go through them which is fine as i don't use them in this code. What are other limitations?

-edit- Related: [Reproducible: Why does passing this object in C break my code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9639844/reproducible-why-does-passing-this-object-in-c-break-my-code)

Answer (score 6):

You can't have extern 'c' that isn't compatible with 'c' - that means no default parameters and no overloaded functions

Comment: Hmm, thats good for thought. What about the return type? Can it be a C++ class with templates? gcc doesnt compile (msvc does). But gcc doesnt seem to like contructors being called in extern C (yet msvc doesnt care). +1 for your info.

Answer (score 3):

I believe the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1041866/what-does-extern-c-in-c-source) gives a good overview of the requirements on extern "c" linkage. The issue I believe you are running into is the last item:

> Linkage from C++ to objects defined in other languages and to objects defined in C++ from other languages is implementation-defined and language-dependent. Only where the object layout strategies of two language implementations are similar enough can such linkage be achieved.

Since your function is returning a class it will be implementation-defined depending on the definition of that class. This explains why it works in one compiler but not another.

The [C++ faq](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/mixing-c-and-cpp) has a few relevant sections on this as well.